# How to remove Custom Options +$10.00 in Magento 1.7

Tags: magento

Hello I am using magento 1.7. I have configurable product and simple products both have custom options... I want to remove the +$10.00 next to the option Example:
custom option: Large +$5.00 I would like it to appear as Large... I still want the price to update on the product's view page.
I tried editing the js/varien/product.js commenting out the str+ but didn't work

```
//str+= ' ' + this.formatPrice(excl, true) + ' (' + this.formatPrice(price, true) + ' ' + this.taxConfig.inclTaxTitle + ')';
            } else {
                //str+= ' ' + this.formatPrice(price, true);
            }
        }
        return str;
    },
formatPrice: function(price, showSign){
    var str = '';
    price = parseFloat(price);
    if(showSign){
        if(price<0){
            //str+= '-';
            price = -price;
        }
        else{
            //str+= '+';
        }
```

Comment: Can you add the line of code where it is called, I have seen this very  recently but I need it to jog my mind.

Comment: Let me see the html code it produce, to see if you could do it will css

Comment: @R.S I have seen the function the produces the string, just a bunch of joins, will be easy to extend and just remove the price at the end. Just can't find it again, driving me nuts.

Comment: Take a look at /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php

Answer (score 7):

Been banging my head on this issue for hours as it relates to configurable products in CE 1.8. The solution for me was actually within /js/varien/configurable.js on lines 236-258. Comment out the following four lines as shown:

```
formatPrice: function(price, showSign){
    var str = '';
    price = parseFloat(price);
    if(showSign){
        if(price<0){
            //str+= '-';
            price = -price;
        }
        else{
            //str+= '+';
        }
    }

    var roundedPrice = (Math.round(price*100)/100).toString();

    if (this.prices && this.prices[roundedPrice]) {
        //str+= this.prices[roundedPrice];
    }
    else {
        //str+= this.priceTemplate.evaluate({price:price.toFixed(2)});
    }
    return str;
},
```

The net effect of commenting out the lines shown above is that the price adjustment of a given option within the drop-down disappears. I've been hunting around the site to see if there are any unintended consequences but haven't seen anything yet.

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to look into [`Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Abstract::_formatPrice()` [link]](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Abstract.php#L112).

It's not possible to rewrite this method using the framework. As the display logic which uses this method potentially touches many areas, I would look into a CSS-based solution. While this may appear hackish, it's likely cleaner than trying to extend each subclass to handle your logic. The following would work for the default theme:

```
#product-options-wrapper span.price-notice,
#product-options-wrapper span.price { display:none }
```

Comment: yeah it's not recommended rewriting that kind of file. I like that hackish solution, it's simple and works. Btw it's been ages not seeing you answer in SO

Comment: Yes I generally prefer to prevent rendering output rather than hiding its display, but the architecture does not make this clean. As to my absence, lots of work and Magento U going on!

Comment: thank you that works, but for the drop down option it still shows the +$0.00

Comment: Indeed, this doesn't help `<select>` custom options. I was tempted to vote down the answer, then I saw who posted it. That would be rude since he taught me the Tao Te Magento.

Answer (score 5):

Using the comment from user "R.S" above I was able to fix this issue for my website.  Here is a screenshot from my website showing the fix works http://tinypic.com/r/5pexz4/5

Find the file

/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php

Go to lines 70 - 74

```
$select->addOption(
                $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
                $_value->getTitle() . ' ' . $priceStr . '',
                array('price' => $this->helper('core')->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false))
            );
```

Remove this code from line 72

```
. ' ' . $priceStr . ''
```

OR  comment out the code

```
$_value->getTitle() /*. ' ' . $priceStr . ''*/,
```

be sure to leave the "," at the end of the statement.  My code now looks like this and works fine.

```
$select->addOption(
                $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
                $_value->getTitle() /*. ' ' . $priceStr . ''*/,
                array('price' => $this->helper('core')->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false))
            );
```

I hope this helps you and other who are looking for the same fix!

Answer (score 2):

Add this JavaScript to `template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

```
<script>    
// Override formatting in "js/varien/configurable.js"
Product.Config.prototype.formatPrice = Product.Config.prototype.formatPrice.wrap(
      function(parentMethod, price, showSign){ return ''; }
);
</script>
```

Or you could create a new JS file with the above code and include it via local.xml in a block for the product detail and product review pages.

Comment: thank you. it worked after trying n number of methods

Answer (score 1):

From @R.S Look at:
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php [L 65-75]

```
        foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
            $priceStr = $this->_formatPrice(array(
                'is_percent' => ($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent') ? true : false,
                'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice(true)
            ), false);
            $select->addOption(
                $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
                $_value->getTitle() . ' ' . $priceStr . '',
                array('price' => $this->helper('core')->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false))
            );
        }
```

I can't test this, but if you remove everything after get title, it should do what you want,  **you will not want to edit like this in your core files** *For testing it is fine.*

```
        foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
            $priceStr = $this->_formatPrice(array(
                'is_percent' => ($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent') ? true : false,
                'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice(true)
            ), false);
            $select->addOption(
                $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
                $_value->getTitle()
            );
        }
```

I would look at best practises to either extend `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select` or copy it out of the Core files.

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1
    app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/ Configurable.php

change this line

```
'template'  => str_replace('%s', '#{price}' $store->getCurrentCurrency()->getOutputFormat()),
```

TO

```
'template'          => Mage::helper('catalog')->__(''),
```

STEP 2
js/varien/product.js
change this function

```
formatPrice: function(price, showSign){ 
    var str = ''; 
    price = parseFloat(price); 
    if(showSign){ 
    if(price<0){ 
    str+= '-'; 
    price = -price; 
    } 
    else{ 
    str+= '+'; 
    } 
}
```

TO

formatPrice: function(price, showSign){

```
var str = ''; 
price = parseFloat(price); 
if(showSign){ 
if(price < 0){ 
str+= ''; 
price = -price; 
} 
else{ 
str+= ''; 
}
```

}
STEP 3
js/varien/configurable.js.js
change this function

```
formatPrice: function(price, showSign){ 
    var str = ''; 
    price = parseFloat(price); 
    if(showSign){ 
    if(price<0){ 
    str+= '-'; 
    price = -price; 
    } 
    else{ 
    str+= '+'; 
    } 
}
```

TO

formatPrice: function(price, showSign){

```
var str = ''; 
price = parseFloat(price); 
if(showSign){ 
if(price < 0){ 
str+= ''; 
price = -price; 
} 
else{ 
str+= ''; 
}
```

}
It works well for me.
I got the answer by the link http://ram-magento.blogspot.in/2011/10/remove-or-price-value-in-drop-down-in.html

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me
setp 01: go to app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/

setp 02: open configurable.phtml file

setp 03 : past following javascript on top of the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    checkoptions();

    jQuery("select.super-attribute-select").change(function(){
        checkoptions();
    });
});

function checkoptions(){
    jQuery("select.super-attribute-select option").each(function(){
        var optiontext = jQuery(this).text();
        var addsignpos = optiontext.indexOf('+');
        var subtractsignpos = optiontext.indexOf('-');
        if(addsignpos>0){
            var result = optiontext.substring(0,addsignpos-1);
            jQuery(this).html(result);
        }

        if(subtractsignpos>0){
            var result = optiontext.substring(0,subtractsignpos-1);
            jQuery(this).html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

original source :http://www.cybernetikz.com/remove-price-configurable-products-dropdown-options-magento/